# localhost index.php missing

Tags: php, localhost

When I updated php5, I see the `It works!` page appears when I go to `http://localhost` instead of getting the localhost's homepage.

I see `/var/www/index.php` is missing.

How should I correct it ?

I have reinstalled Php & Apache but the problem remains.

Answer (score 2):

Apache doesn't create a index.php.
So you have two options:

- Create your index.php
- Modify your configuration (probabily /etc/apache2/sites-available/default) to point to another folder, where there is your index.
  If you want to modify your configuration you have to change **DocumentRoot** and the first **< Directory >**

Comment: Is there a way to get the original page back ? I am not sure how did the page got erased in the first place.

Comment: There is no original page. Only page you have when you install Apache is index.html, and looks like http://paste.ubuntu.com/5939372/

Comment: I was expecting a page like this http://www.google.com.np/imgres?imgurl=http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/images/4/42/Wamp_server_localhost_view.jpg%3F20100525095402&imgrefurl=http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_install_WAMP_on_Windows&usg=__SACiicBKfAtCOS1Likbq9s8m9Jo=&h=1020&w=945&sz=95&hl=en&start=1&zoom=1&tbnid=8I27gRG-_R-mrM:&tbnh=150&tbnw=139&ei=Mnb7UeOfMcjlrAfwhYGYDw&itbs=1&sa=X&ved=0CCsQrQMwAA

Comment: @maan81 WAMP might do that, but a standard LAMP stack doesn't stuff php files anywhere by default. You end up with a fairly clean installation.

Comment: Ok, I just renamed/deleted the index.html and lol.... I get the folders [projects] I had. Wonder why I didn't think of it before ...